# How to grep response to figure out how many calls got timed out?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, grep

I have a curl command which is calling one of our service so if my service timesout, it returns JSON response like below:

```
[{"results":{"response":null},"error":{"errorCode":1001,"message":"Service Timeout","status":"FAILURE"}}]
```

Below is my curl command when I run, I will get above response if there is any timeout

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer some token here" "http://localhost:8080/v2/line?&clientid=120";
```

I am running my above curl command in a for loop for x number of times. Now I want to see how many calls got timed out by checking `"message"` in the JSON response? I mean if I made 1 million calls then how many calls got timedout and what was the percentage of timeout?

So I got below one line for loop which calls curl command but whenever I run it always gives 1 as an answer which is wrong. I mean I can see lot of calls getting timedout but every time it gives 1 as an answer. Is there anything wrong I am doing?

```
for ((i=1;i<=1000000;i++)); do
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer some token here" "http://localhost:8080/v2/line?&clientid=120"
done \
| grep -wcoE '"errorCode":1001'
```

This is what I see as an output after running the command:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0  12798      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17384
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0   4591      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7290
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0   6318      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8370
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0   5252      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7793
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   226  100   226    0     0   6139      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8071
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make curl silent with the `-s` flag:

```
curl -s --header "Authorization: Bearer some token here" "http://localhost:8080/v2/line?&clientid=120"
```

Or redirect its error output to `/dev/null` like so:

```
curl -s --header "Authorization: Bearer some token here" "http://localhost:8080/v2/line?&clientid=120" 2>/dev/null
```

Also, your version of counting won't work as expected. Here's how you could fix it:

```
timedout_count=0
for ((i=1;i<=1000000;i++)); do
    curl -s --header "Authorization: Bearer some token here" "http://localhost:8080/v2/line?&clientid=120" | 
        grep -q '"errorCode":1001' && timedout_count=$(( timedout_count + 1 ))
done 

echo "Timed out $timedout_count times"
```

Comment: I mean my question was - I see lot of timedout calls but everytime it gives 1 as an answer so something is wrong with my command I guess? Sorry for the confusion, I have updated it to make it clear.

Comment: Updated the answer